# Catching a failed authorization policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In .Net Core 2, suppose there is an authorization policy that checks that specific claims exist for the user:

```
public class CompletedProfileRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<CompletedProfileRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CompletedProfileRequirement requirement)
    {
        // Check that all required claims exist
        if (/* invalid user claims */) {
            context.Fail();
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

And we stick the policy check on top of an MVC controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CompletedProfile")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     // Controller stuff
}
```

How can I write an `IAuthorizationFilter` so that we can catch a failure on this particular `CompletedProfileRequirement` policy so that we can redirect the user to a page where they may complete their profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [authorization documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#accessing-mvc-request-context-in-handlers), it's possible to access the MVC context from your `AuthorizationHandler`:

> Frameworks such as MVC or Jabbr are free to add any object to the `Resource` property on the `AuthorizationHandlerContext` to pass extra information.
>
> For example, MVC passes an instance of `AuthorizationFilterContext` in the `Resource` property. This property provides access to `HttpContext`, `RouteData`, and everything else provided by MVC and Razor Pages.

Therefore, you can do something like this:

```
public class CompletedProfileRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<CompletedProfileRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CompletedProfileRequirement requirement)
    {
        // Check that all required claims exist
        if (/* invalid user claims */) {

            // retrieve MVC context
            if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)
            {
                // we still need to mark the requirement as succeeded, 
                // otherwise responde code is 401 unauthorized
                context.Succeed(requirement);

                // HTTP 302 temporary redirect to your page
                mvcContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Wherever", false);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up implementing but it feels like a misuse of the handlers. I would expect that you could "catch" specific policy failures somewhere in the pipeline

Comment: We want to do the same redirection in multiple requirement handlers, so this is not ideal. Ideally we'd like to have a single layer in the pipeline above the authorization handler calls such that, if authorization fails on any, it can be caught and handled in one place (we do some complex checks based on cookie policy etc. to determine what to do for unauthorized requests)

Comment: Thanks for the code. For me this shows how bad the handler design is today :/

Answer (score -1):

You should add your policy with requirments to authorization on application startup, like:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CompletedProfile", builder =>
            {
                builder.AddRequirements(new CompletedProfileRequirement());
            });
        });
```

And register handlers, like:

```
 services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, CompletedProfileRequirementHandler>();
```

**UPD:**

For redirecting you should inject and use in controller:

```
IAuthorizationService authorizationService
```

And invoke:

```
var result = _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, someObject, "CompletedProfile");
if (!result.Succeeded)
    return RedirectToAction("CompleteProfileAction");
```

Comment: This explains how to add a requirement to a policy, but that's not what the question is..

Comment: @Métoule Oh, sorry for that, I was a little bit tired, so I've completed the whole answer.